# Use Loopback3 OR wait for Loopback4 (ES2017)

Tags: node.js, api, ecmascript-6, loopback

I am going to start a new long-term project and I am responsible of API development.
I decided to use [Loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/index.html) due to its various features for API rapid development, but it is now built with es5 in contrast of [Loopback4](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Examples-and-tutorials.html)
that will come with **ES2017** and many modern tools as I see but still in **Pre-Beta** version.

After some search I found some trials in using ES6 with Loopback3:

This question [Loopback models in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006578/loopback-models-in-es6)

and this issue https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2083#issuecomment-281201056

and no complete/official solution.

Also I think that the feature of **upgrade** from 3 to 4 will not be available.

**The question is**: should I use Loopback 3 now with es6 and [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel).
**OR** use another tool for the current project to avoid refactoring/rebuilding in future, and wait untill  Loopback4 is released

Comment: ES6 is fully supported on node (maybe except for modules)